# VPAID javascript mediafile that loads a random VAST

Tags: javascript, ads, vast

I want a VPAID javascript to pick a random VAST from a list of XML files I have, and load it through the ad container.

I know how to change the slot's DOM and change the `<video>`'s `src` attribute so it'll so a different video, but I don't understand how can I load a new VAST into the ad container.
I guess I can dynamically load (again) in the media file script the ima3.js library and apply the VAST to the ad container, but I think there's a simpler way. Am I right? Is there a better practice to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Does "want a VPAID-JS pick a random VAST" mean, it's your VPAID? And if you were able to implement VPAID, where is the problem? If it's not yours VPAID, please clarify what you are asking for!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a server that picks the XML from a list and return the correct XML. I believe this is the industry standard.

e.g.

1. create a service called ads.com
2. ads.com runs a function that randomly picks an XML and returns it
3. when the SSP calls ads.com it gets a random XML

With this methodology you could serve different XMLs based on settings such as user cookies or device.

Comment: The problem with this method, is that the service URL can't be cached, because it will return different content each time.

Comment: Why would you want the service to be cached if you want to return a different XML every time?

Comment: Unless you don't want to introduce a different XML and only want to serve a different content. In that case you could use AWS Cloudfront that has a CND service looping through multiple media with the same URL.

Comment: I want to randomly check VAST tag. So let's say I get once the tag http://example.com/vast1.xml, and then http://example.com/vast2.xml, those too XMLs will be cached, and next time the user will get those tags it'll load faster.

Comment: A couple of things:

1. XMLs load very fast already since they're very very small
2. You can only feed the SSP/publisher video player a single XML. So you'll need to pick the XML before sending the information to the video player. The publisher is not going to choose the XML randomly for you. Hence you need an XML picker service that fetches the correct XML. It might take 10 ms slower since we're talking about a few KB of data.